# RollupError when building Vue 3 application with Vite and deploying on Vercel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, devops, vite, vercel

I'm encountering an error while trying to build my Vue 3 application with Vite and deploying it on Vercel. The application runs perfectly in the development environment, but I'm facing an issue during the build process.

The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
RollupError: Could not resolve "../components/childform/childForm.vue" from "src/pages/HomePage.vue"
at error (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2124:30)
at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23990:24)
at file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23952:26
```

Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

I have verified that the path to the childForm.vue component is correct. It is located at "../components/childform/childForm.vue" relative to the src/pages/HomePage.vue file.

I suspect that the problem might be related to the build configuration or the way Vercel handles the build process. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error.

Comment: I'm having the same build errors - except I'm deploying to azure.
I've run the prod build locally and used vite preview to test it out - no issues there.

Not sure what is causing the build to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your letter-casing in your filenames and imports are identical between your repository and local machine. Make sure 'git config core.ignorecase false' is set in your environment.